# How can I save sessions into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help regarding saving sessions into mysql.

Right now I am using php normal sessions for my login system.

Here is my code:

**auth.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db.inc.php');
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pwd=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);
$sql="Select member_id,email,password,nama,type from users where email='$email' and password=md5('$pwd')";
$exec=mysql_query($sql);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($exec);
if ($result['type'] == "member")
{
$_SESSION['nama']=$result['nama'];
$_SESSION['id']=$result['member_id'];
header('location:member.php');
}
else
{
    echo 'Anda gagal login';
   header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

**member.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('output_fns.php');
if(!$_SESSION['nama'])
{
    header('location:index.php');
}
else
{
do_kepala('Member');
echo 'Welcome &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $_SESSION['nama'];
menu_member();
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for here...

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to [define custom functions for the session save handlers](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) . You also have to, of course, make a table on your MySQL database. There are many intricate steps, all of which you can find [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2037).

Comment: session_set_save_handler() is exactly what you're looking for.